# Is there any work-around to get train() function of caret package work from within Rstudio?

Tags: r, compiler-construction, rstudio, r-caret

I was walking through the examples of the very nice book "Applied Predictive Modeling" by Max Kuhn and Kjell Johnson, unfortunately I got stuck in one of the examples using the `train()` function and one of the `GermanCredit` dataset provided by the `caret` package for cross-validation of Support Vector Machines:

```
library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
library(caret)
# preparing the data
data(GermanCredit)
GermanCredit <- GermanCredit[, -nearZeroVar(GermanCredit)]
GermanCredit$CheckingAccountStatus.lt.0 <- NULL
GermanCredit$SavingsAccountBonds.lt.100 <- NULL
GermanCredit$EmploymentDuration.lt.1 <- NULL
GermanCredit$EmploymentDuration.Unemployed <- NULL
GermanCredit$Personal.Male.Married.Widowed <- NULL
GermanCredit$Property.Unknown <- NULL
GermanCredit$Housing.ForFree <- NULL
set.seed(100)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(GermanCredit$Class, p = .8)[[1]]
GermanCreditTrain <- GermanCredit[ inTrain, ]
GermanCreditTest  <- GermanCredit[-inTrain, ]

# Grid selection for `sigma` and `cost` tuning parameters:    
library(kernlab)
set.seed(231)
sigDist <- sigest(Class ~ ., data = GermanCreditTrain, frac = 1)
svmTuneGrid <- data.frame(.sigma = sigDist[1], .C = 2^(-2:7))

# SVM classification and cross-validation
svmFit <- train(Class ~ .,
                data = GermanCreditTrain,
                method = "svmRadial",
                preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                tuneGrid = svmTuneGrid,
                trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 5, 
                                         classProbs =  TRUE))
```

and it has thrown this error:

```
Error in comp(expr, env = envir, options = list(suppressUndefined = TRUE)) : 
  could not find function "makeCenv"
```

sometimes this error message:

```
Loading required package: class
Warning: namespace ‘compiler’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘GermanCredit’
Error in comp(expr, env = envir, options = list(suppressUndefined = TRUE)) : 
  could not find function "makeCenv"
In addition: Warning message:
executing %dopar% sequentially: no parallel backend registered
```

Then I learned that `makeCenv()` is in the `doMC` package that was suggested as alternative for parallel computation or parallel processing, but I wouldn't go for this package since it is not available in Windows platform, I guess. Any alternative?

**Update:**
These errors appeared only when the code was run under `Rstudio IDE`, things were fine from the default R console, so the problem is local to Rstudio, I guess. The time was a little bit long in R console (about 8min), though, I wonder how to speed up things given the hardware specs mentioned below.

My sessioninfo() output is here (Rstudio):

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] datasets  grid      splines   utils     stats     graphics  grDevices methods  
[9] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] proxy_0.4-10                    e1071_1.6-1                    
 [3] class_7.3-9                     kernlab_0.9-19                 
 [5] caret_5.17-7                    foreach_1.4.1                  
 [7] AppliedPredictiveModeling_1.1-4 CORElearn_0.9.42               
 [9] rpart_4.1-3                     xtable_1.7-1                   
[11] knitr_1.5                       texreg_1.30                    
[13] pastecs_1.3-15                  boot_1.3-9                     
[15] gridExtra_0.9.1                 reshape2_1.2.2                 
[17] plyr_1.8                        scales_0.2.3                   
[19] ggplot2_0.9.3.1                 vcdExtra_0.5-11                
[21] gnm_1.0-6                       vcd_1.3-1                      
[23] corrplot_0.73                   RColorBrewer_1.0-5             
[25] car_2.0-19                      Hmisc_3.13-0                   
[27] Formula_1.1-1                   cluster_1.14.4                 
[29] xlsx_0.5.5                      xlsxjars_0.5.0                 
[31] rJava_0.9-5                     lmPerm_1.1-2                   
[33] coin_1.0-23                     survival_2.37-4                
[35] GPArotation_2012.3-1            psych_1.3.12                   
[37] sos_1.3-8                       brew_1.0-6                     
[39] data.table_1.8.10               mice_2.18                      
[41] nnet_7.3-7                      MASS_7.3-29                    
[43] lattice_0.20-23                

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] codetools_0.2-8   colorspace_1.2-4  dichromat_2.0-0   digest_0.6.4     
 [5] evaluate_0.5.1    formatR_0.10      gtable_0.1.2      iterators_1.0.6  
 [9] labeling_0.2      Matrix_1.1-0      modeltools_0.2-21 munsell_0.4.2    
[13] mvtnorm_0.9-9996  proto_0.3-10      qvcalc_0.8-8      relimp_1.0-3     
[17] stats4_3.0.2      stringr_0.6.2     tcltk_3.0.2       tools_3.0.2
```

sessionInfo() output from default R console:

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] datasets  grDevices grid      splines   graphics  utils     stats    
[8] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] e1071_1.6-1     class_7.3-9     kernlab_0.9-19  caret_5.17-7   
 [5] foreach_1.4.1   cluster_1.14.4  lattice_0.20-23 reshape2_1.2.2 
 [9] plyr_1.8        scales_0.2.3    ggplot2_0.9.3.1 lmPerm_1.1-2   
[13] coin_1.0-23     survival_2.37-4 sos_1.3-8       brew_1.0-6     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] codetools_0.2-8    colorspace_1.2-4   compiler_3.0.2     dichromat_2.0-0   
 [5] digest_0.6.3       gtable_0.1.2       iterators_1.0.6    labeling_0.2      
 [9] MASS_7.3-29        modeltools_0.2-21  munsell_0.4.2      mvtnorm_0.9-9996  
[13] proto_0.3-10       RColorBrewer_1.0-5 stats4_3.0.2       stringr_0.6.2     
[17] tools_3.0.2
```

**Questions:**

1. There must be an interaction with `Rstudio` since it worked well in the default R console, based on the two sessionInfo() outputs of default R console and Rstudio, the difference was `compiler` package. Strange, this pkg cannot be found in CRAN, I found a note here: 
   http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/compiler/compile 
   saying that load(compiler) would be enough, when I did this in Rstudio: it was not possible with this error message:

   Error: package ‘compiler’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it

**Update**
It worked finally from withing Rstudio after copy & paste the compiler package library from that of default R lib path to that of Rstudio lib path, but still the time is too long (about 8min), I would post a separate question of parallel processing given the hardware below and windows if that would help to find an answer sooner.

1. My laptop is 2.1GHz dual core processor, 3GB, windows 32bit, any idea how to do parallel processing with `train()` function? can you pls issue the R code for this, I would be very grateful indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caret code base is completely independent of doMC or any of the other "do" packages. I don't have a windows system to test with here, but I am 99% sure that this is not a reproducible problem. The package is tested nightly in several places (e.g. R-Forge) and across 3-4 different OS's, including Windows. I have never seen this issue come up, even when I've taught classes on the package to large audiences exclusively using Windows.

My guess is that you accidentally called a doMC function somewhere (even though it was not listed in your sessionInfo out).

It would be helpful if someone else can try to reproduce this error.

Thanks,

Max

Comment: It can't be due to calling `doMC` somewhere else I would exclude this one. The error message keeps pointing out to `makeCenv()` but this time with `namespace ‘compiler’ is not available `, pls see the update error message above. I hope there would be a remedy to this.

Comment: It worked finally but only in the default R console without any error, it took several minutes to accomplish the job, so there must be an interaction with Rstudio, I updated the question. I wonder how to set up parallel processing under Windows 32bit, my laptop is dual core 2.1GHz, RAM 3GB.

Comment: I noticed the difference between the two sessionInfos() of default R console and Rstudio is the compiler package which appeared in the error message, this package cannot be loaded from withing R studio `Error: package ‘compiler’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it`.

Comment: yes, I installed the `compiler_3.0.2` version as copy & paste couldn't downloaded from CRAN, and it worked. Seems that this package ships already with R, but for some reason I had an old version in the Rstudio lib path, which caused all the hassles.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade R

```
    sudo su
    echo "deb http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
    apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
    apt-get update
    apt-get upgrade
```